# not able to update values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `config_table` with fields `id`,`config_value`.
I want to update `config value` as below for the `id ='6'`

```
if($user->status_id=='1' && $user->reviewed!='0'){
    if($sl_flag==0 && $requestor_role->role_id==7){ 
        $status="Waiting for Review"; 
        $title="Waiting for Review";
    }elseif($sl_flag==0){ 
        $status="Waiting for dept.owner approval";
        $title="Waiting for Deptment owner approval ";
    }else{ 
        $status="Waiting for prac.owner approval";
        $title="Waiting for practice owner approval";
    }
}
```

I have updated as

```
update config_table set config_value='     if($user->status_id=='1' && $user->reviewed!='0'){
if($sl_flag==0 && $requestor_role->role_id==7){ 
    $status="Waiting for Review"; 
    $title="Waiting for Review";
}elseif($sl_flag==0){ 
    $status="Waiting for dept.owner approval";
    $title="Waiting for Deptment owner approval ";
}else{ 
    $status="Waiting for prac.owner approval";
    $title="Waiting for practice owner approval";
}
}' where id='6';
```

I have tried this in putty server but I caught error in syntax near }  for each and every line.how to update this

Comment: You used `''` for the config_value but then in there you use again `''`. If you wish so, escape them or just change them all to `""` except for the first and last one from `config_value`. This is possible in this case as PHP is loosely typed.

Comment: What's the point to save php code in DB? Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: ya I need to save php code

Comment: What's the point? You're ruining the separation of concerns, your database becomes dependant to the application. Tomorrow, you don't want php, but ASP.net in example, or any other language for your application. What are you going to do? Storing code in database is a very bad practice, that can lead to security breaches.

Comment: I have written an answer to your post but do advice you taking @Cid's advice and update your way of work. Keep it all separated of each other.

Comment: just do all your php logic before, it'll all become easier to maintain and better code :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `''` within the `config_value` where you also started with `''`. So it thinks it ends there, but you only want to assign a value. There are several options within this code to fix it. First of all: PHP is loosely typed, so you might just update the `''` within the `config_value` to `""`.

```
update config_table set config_value='     if($user->status_id=="1" && $user->reviewed!="0"){
 if($sl_flag==0 && $requestor_role->role_id==7)
 { $status="Waiting for Review"; 
 $title="Waiting for Review";
 } 
 elseif($sl_flag==0)
 { $status="Waiting for dept.owner approval";
 $title="Waiting for Deptment owner approval ";
 }
 else
 { $status="Waiting for prac.owner approval";
 $title="Waiting for practice owner approval";
 }
}' where id="6";
```

Another option would be escaping the values that you check using `''`. This can be done by adding a `\` before the `'`.

`value = 'if($user->status_id==\'1\') { /*your code*/ }'`

Comment: I assume he does else I don't know why he posted it like this way. I think you want to ask this question to @user3386779. If he wants to excecute this, you want to put `'. .'` in there to execute the code itself.

Comment: Removed the above part again (`'..'`) as it's not necessary for his question. @user3386779 just stated this in the comments of his post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use addslashes like this:

```
$value = <<< END
     if($user->status_id=='1' && $user->reviewed!='0'){
    if($sl_flag==0 && $requestor_role->role_id==7){ 
        $status="Waiting for Review"; 
        $title="Waiting for Review";
    }elseif($sl_flag==0){ 
        $status="Waiting for dept.owner approval";
        $title="Waiting for Deptment owner approval ";
    }else{ 
        $status="Waiting for prac.owner approval";
        $title="Waiting for practice owner approval";
    }
    }
END;

    update config_table set config_value=$value where id='6';
```

Comment: tried caught You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' && $user->reviewed!='0'){
if($sl_flag==0 && $requestor_role->role_id==7)
{ $s' at line 1